How to execute a pywinauto automation script through an Azure DevOps pipeline, as it requires an active GUI to access the elements?
I've developed an pywinauto automation script to automate an desktop application and pushed it to a repo in order to execute it through a pipeline in an agent machine, when I try to execute manually it in the agent machine its working good. But when I try to execute it directly from pipeline the script is not able to identify the elements.
I've tried the traditional method of executing a pipeline and it failed as I guess pywinauto requires the application to be in its field of view to access the elements. How to execute my code directly from pipeline?
File "features\steps\launch_app_steps.py", line 16, in step_given_User_is_logged_to_app_with_SSO_login
2024-05-22T06:22:39.8642301Z           wait_until(timeout=55, retry_interval=0.7, func=lambda: context.signinWindow.exists())
2024-05-22T06:22:39.8643588Z         File "C:\Agent\Python\Lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 375, in wait_until
2024-05-22T06:22:39.8643885Z           raise err
2024-05-22T06:22:39.8644165Z       pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError: timed out


Maybe this guide would be helpful: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_execution.html Though there is no recipe specifically for Azure pipelines. If you find it, please let me know, I will add it.

As suggested in my answer below, you need to set up a self-hosted agent and configure the agent to run in interactive mode. @NithishDuraikannan

You need to set up a self-hosted agent and configure the agent to run in interactive mode.

Every time when you need to run pipeline on this agent, you first need to manually logon on the agent machine and go to the installation directory of the agent, then double click the script file 'run.cmd' to start the agent. It will open a command prompt to listen if there is any job is requesting to run on this agent. So, you need to keep this command prompt open until the job is completed and no other jobs are requesting to use this agent.


But we cannot open the agent machine each and every time, right? That's the reason we are using the pipeline as a CI/CD solution so that things are taken care of automatically

@NithishDuraikannan, Since your pywinauto script needs interactive, you must configure the self-hosed agent to run in interactive mode. To use the interactive mode self-hosed agent, it is required you to manual logon the machine at first.

Now, actually I have set the Interactive session value in Agent capabilities to "True", even still I'm get this timeout error as the code is unable to identify the locators, but I am sure my application is getting launched because I have added a code to kill the app at last that is getting executed

@NithishDuraikannan, To configure the self-hosted agent to run in interactive mode, you need to reconfigure the agent like as my above answer showing. It does not make any effect if you just add the agent capability Interactive with true value.
